# DrayTek Vigor 2830 open port issue

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, ports

We're using a Vigor2830 for routing VoIP/SIP traffic. One of the ports required to be open is 5090 for TCP/UDP. Going into the open ports section of the Vigor menu we have opened all the ports required but when running port checker against 5090 TCP the checker is saying the port is closed. Running the checker against 5090 UDP shows that the port is open and all the other ports are open for both protocols. We've tried entering 5090 TCP and 5090 UDP as separate entries but this has made no difference.
Something is obviously amiss here but I have no idea what, can anyone offer any advice?

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is that [SIP is only used for managing the connection](http://blog.lithiumblue.com/2007/07/understanding-relationship-between-sip.html) - the actual call data (RDP data) is not transmitted on port 5090, thus you need to do more then just open port 5090 for things to work - and indeed depending on your setup, RDP may be going to a different IP address to the SIP server !

(Unfortunately if you need more help on getting this working through the firewall we would need more information about the setup, ie where are the clients and server located etc.

BTW, SIP does not generally require TCP.

Comment: Actually port 5090 is not used for SIP itself, that's on port 5060. 5090 is used as the port enabling the Windows softphones to communicate with the on-premise PBX.<br>

Comment: The PBX has two NICs: 192.168.x.x for internal data and 172.16.x.x for voice data. The PBX's external IP address is linked to the 172.16.x.x address.
The PBX software is provided by 3CX and we have followed their instructions for opening the needed ports on our router.